# API Manager Changes in file catalina-server.xml

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I need some changes in the file:

**Path**

```
[API-Manager]/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml
```

In specific in this part where say localhost:

[image]

But in the APIM version 3.0.0 or superior all changes in this files discards because any server configuration is: [API-HOME]/repository/conf/deployment.toml, reference: https://github.com/wso2/docs-apim/issues/498

Where is the file correct and path for edit this part?

Comment: Do you need to change the host in APIM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This value isn't templated at the moment. As a workaround you can edit the template file at

> /repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml.j2

and set defaultHost to the preferred value.